# How to find element by xpath that has same class, name etc

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

There are two buttons with same class, text etc. I have to find and click each.

[image]

```
<a class="jsx-1291462554"><button style="padding: 12px 15px 10px; border-radius: 4px; font: 500 15px / 16px hind; color: white; background-color: rgb(18, 83, 181); justify-content: center; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; outline: none; border: none; width: 162px;"><span class="jsx-1291462554 magzter__buttonText">Choose</span></button></a>
```

Comment: whats inside the second button? same text choose ?

Answer (score 0):

//section[contains(@class,'chooseplanTitle')]//button[1]
//section[contains(@class,'chooseplanTitle')]//button[2]

Answer (score 0):

If is possible, put something to differentiate the buttons's mapping. But if it isn't possible, these mappings will solve

```
(//section[contains(@class, 'twocol')]/a)[1]

(//section[contains(@class, 'twocol')]/a)[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

to enable the automatic clicking of a button, we use the `XPath` function, which is in the class `By`.

---

1.Version

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class ='CLASS NAME']")).Click();
```

---

2.Version

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[normalize-space(.)='NAME']/button")).Click();
```

---

To enable an automatic input into the text field we can also use the function `CssSelector` which is located in the class `By`.

---

```
        IWebElement usernameInput = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='username']"));
        IWebElement passwordInput = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='password']"));

        usernameInput.SendKeys("YourUsername");
        passwordInput.SendKeys("YourPassword");
```

Answer (score 0):

find first and second element that matches the below locator :

```
(//a[@class="jsx-1291462554"]/button)[1]
(//a[@class="jsx-1291462554"]/button)[2]
```

find all elements with tag button and is a first child of 'a' with class specified:

```
//a[@class="jsx-1291462554"]/button[1]
```

css equalent of first xpath :

```
a.jsx-1291462554>button:nth-of-type(1)
a.jsx-1291462554>button:nth-of-type(2)
```

css equalent of second xpath :

```
a.jsx-1291462554>button:nth-child(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the elements are a dynamic elements. So to `click()` on the first <kbd>Choose</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//p[starts-with(., 'Choose the plan that')]//following::a[1]/button/span[text()='Choose']")));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='jsx-1291462554']"));

        links.get(0).click();
        //Wait here for some action to happen
        links.get(1).click();
```

The xpath varies depending on what you actually want to click, if the button element replace with:

```
//a[@class='jsx-1291462554']/button
```

If the button's click action changes the DOM you might encounter a StaleElementReference, in which case you may need to refetch (findElements) again before selecting the 2nd one.